# How to optimize django-import-export?

Tags: python, django, django-import-export

I have a data in Excel around 20,000 records. I using django-import-export extension for import data.I tried to import data but very slow about 10 minute. I think one thing to make it slow that is django-import-export render 20,000 records on preview table. I want to know how to speedup ?

Answer (score 0):

I made some notes on speeding up django-import-export [here](https://gist.github.com/matthewhegarty/f8a6fc7d06ae00176b15c885faca6c1f).  Using the optimisations I describe I could import 20k rows in ~5 seconds on my dev laptop.

The best way is to override `save_instance()` to use [`bulk_create()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create), but there are other optimisations you can make.